# Withdraw eth from contract address

Tags: ether

I accidentally sent Eth to a contract address. The contract was created by my eth address. Im not sure how but it looks like it is associated with my sending NFTS to my ledger etherscan.io/address/0xb36d0655799f8bd1adcc46c13d643c5b0ada897a

I have verified the address in Etherscan so can access the contract

Is there anyway to withdraw from the current contract?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `selfdestruct` which can destroy all codes and then return tokens to the address called `selfdestruct`. If you are able to call the function, it is possible for you to get the fund back.

Since I do not see your code, I have no idea if you have function `selfdestruct` in the smart contract. If the function is written in your smart contract, you can call the function and destroy the smart contract.

If you do not have the function in the smart contract, you must have a function to run `delegatecall`. Since the `delegatecall` in the contract A can run the code passed by another contract, it is possible to create `selfdestruct` in contract B and make contract A to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Only if your original contract has the withdraw function, otherwise I'm afraid it's locked.

[contracts-that-lock-ether](https://github.com/crytic/slither/wiki/Detector-Documentation#contracts-that-lock-ether)

Comment: Are you able to tell me if this contract is locked? I cant seem to find it in the code? https://etherscan.io/address/0xd7830d8224B65eaF24dE37748f69820F81368f59#code

Comment: @BigJH Yes you can! Your contract is an upgradeable proxy, so you can change its implementation to a contract that would allow you to withdraw ether (as explained in the other answer) You can contact me on discord, my id is in my bio :)

Comment: Thanks @Foxxxey Ive reached out via discord